Azure AI services Conversation summary. More details for ParticipanId and Role in ConversationItems
I'm testing Azure AI services Conversation summary using this QuickStart.
I noticed that Role in ConversationItems is not required to get the summary. And actually, result will be the same with and without Role specified (at least for recap mode).
I also see updated C# SDK example with models here, which doesn't use Role at all (only uses ParticipantId required). The ParticipantId is just a string, which probably means that I can specify anything that I want to classify different groups in ConversationItems, like a Guid for example. However, it's not clear from the documentation.
My questions are the following:

Is it possible to avoid adding Roles without degradation of the quality of generated summary?
Is it possible to use any type of strings for ParticipantId, not just Agent/Customer as in example, but Guids, or any other Identifier types to classify groups of items?

Based on my tests I see that it is possible however would be good to know more details about these parameters to avoid issues with not accurate summary results.

Hi @AlexanderBikkuzhin In the current version of the SDK you need to include the values Issue or Resolution in the SummaryAspect ActionContent.

The API expects the role to be explicitly defined for each conversation item when performing summarization tasks. Without defining the roles, a 400 (Bad Request) error will occur.

You can only omit the role in some cases of specifically performing a task like "ConversationalSummarizationTask"
Yes, you can use any type of string for ParticipantId and The only supported values for the role field are: Customer and Agent while giving vaules  it give 400 error.
Refer this  MSDOC to use  conversation with Conversation Summarization
Sample Code for Conversation Summarization
  var data = new
            {
                analysisInput = new
                {
                    conversations = new[]
                    {
                        new
                        {
                            id = "conversation-1",
                            language = "en",
                            modality = "text",
                            conversationItems = new[]
                            {
                                new
                                {
                                    id = "1",
                                    participantId = "12345ravi",
                                   role = "Agent",
                                    text = "Hello, you’re chatting with Rene. How may I help you?"
                                },
                                new
                                {
                                    id = "2",
                                    participantId = "67890",
                                       role = "Customer",
                                    text = "Hi, I tried to set up wifi connection for Smart Brew 300 coffee machine, but it didn’t work."
                                },
                                new
                                {
                                    id = "3",
                                    participantId = "12345",
                                    role = "Agent",
                                    text = "I’m sorry to hear that. Could you please try pressing the wifi button for 3 seconds and let me know if the light blinks?"
                                },
                                new
                                {
                                    id = "4",
                                    participantId = "67890ttt",
                                    role = "Customer",
                                    text = "Yes, the light is blinking."
                                },
                                new
                                {
                                    id = "5",
                                    participantId = "12345",
                                  role = "Agent",
                                    text = "Great! Now, check your Contoso Coffee app for a connection prompt."
                                },
                                new
                                {
                                    id = "6",
                                    participantId = "67890",
                                   role = "Customer",
                                    text = "No prompt is appearing."
                                },
                                new
                                {
                                    id = "7",
                                    participantId = "12345",
                                  role = "Agent",
                                    text = "I’ll check for alternative solutions. Please hold on."
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                tasks = new[]
                {
                    new
                    {
                        taskName = "conversation-summarization",
                        kind = "ConversationalSummarizationTask",
                        parameters = new
                        {
                            summaryAspects = new[] { "issue", "resolution" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

    
            Operation<BinaryData> operation = await client.AnalyzeConversationsAsync(
                WaitUntil.Completed,
                RequestContent.Create(data)
            );
            using JsonDocument result = JsonDocument.Parse(operation.Value.ToStream());
            Console.WriteLine("Full Response:");
            Console.WriteLine(result.RootElement.ToString()); 
            if (result.RootElement.TryGetProperty("tasks", out JsonElement tasksElement))
            {

                foreach (var task in tasksElement.GetProperty("items").EnumerateArray())
                {
              
                    if (task.TryGetProperty("results", out JsonElement resultsElement))
                    {
               
                        if (resultsElement.TryGetProperty("conversations", out JsonElement conversationsElement))
                        {
                   
                            foreach (var conversation in conversationsElement.EnumerateArray())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Conversation ID: {conversation.GetProperty("id").GetString()}"
                                if (conversation.TryGetProperty("summaries", out JsonElement summariesElement))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Summaries:");
                                    foreach (var summary in summariesElement.EnumerateArray())
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine($"Aspect: {summary.GetProperty("aspect").GetString()}");
                                        Console.WriteLine($"Text: {summary.GetProperty("text").GetString()}");
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("No summaries found.");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("No conversations found in results.");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No results found in task.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No tasks found in the response.");
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:


I'm using exactly ConversationalSummarizationTask. I noticed that I could set random ParticipantId and omit role for "recap" and "narrative" mode. issue-resolution mode works only with Role and ParticipantId like Customer/Agent, at least it doesn't work with ParticapanId as Guid for me. while recap and narrative work well.

Ok I think I found the issue, dashes are not accepted in ParticipantId when using issue\resolution mode and Role required. But then ParticipantId as well as Role ignored for recap or narrative mode I guess, because it works well with random Guid for both parameters for me. And setting Role or meaningful ParticipantId doesn't impact the sumamry. Does it correct?

yes, correct participantId Can be random GUIDs and ParticipantId doesn't impact the summary. glad to know issue got resloved.

Yes ,Setting role don't effect summary
